# Is there a way to run PS script in SQL server using t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql, powershell-4.0

Is it possible to execute below powershell script using t-sql ?

$Isconnected= (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList test3,3389).Connected

Comment: How about executing the above as a SQL Agent job?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping everything being passed to the `Command` in quotes (`"`)?

Comment: How can we do that ?

Comment: No actual requirement is to run using t-sql

Comment: xp_cmdshell accepts only a constant string, no variables. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Serg that isn't true. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04w9r.png)

Comment: @Larnu thanks for clarification. Never used it this way.

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: SQL Agent will run the script as a T-SQL job itself.

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumarSingh for this however i am willing to execute this via t-sql as I do have some other dependencies

Comment: So, from T-SQL you want to start a `cmd` command that has to launch PowerShell to run a script which will in turn kick off T-SQL commands. My advice is to scrap this and start over with an actual client application (even if that application it itself just a PowerShell script); you will be doing not only yourself but also all future maintainers a huge favor. Even if you are absolutely married to T-SQL, you can still package this as a PowerShell job and then start that job from T-SQL. One level of quoting is tough enough, you've got three here.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert for the response. Is it possible to quote below one via t-sql $Isconnected= (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList test3,3389).Connected